# Passing function as argument in F#

Tags: f#

In the following example, I'm receiving the error "No overloads match for method 'op_Subtraction'."

```
open System

type EmployeeStatus = 
    | Active
    | NotActive

type EnrollmentPeriod = 
    | JanuaryFirst
    | JulyFirst
    | PeriodNotApplicable

let DetermineTargettedEnrollmentDate targettedEnrollmentDate (relativeDate : DateTime) = 
    match targettedEnrollmentDate with
    | EnrollmentPeriod.JanuaryFirst -> new DateTime(relativeDate.Year + 1,1,1)
    | EnrollmentPeriod.JulyFirst -> new DateTime(relativeDate.Year,7,1)
    | EnrollmentPeriod.PeriodNotApplicable -> relativeDate

let ProjectDaysWorkedSinceJan1 employeeStatus targettedEnrollmentPeriod (relativeDate : DateTime) =
    let januaryFirst = DateTime(relativeDate.Year,1,1)
    let targettedEnrollmentDate = DetermineTargettedEnrollmentDate targettedEnrollmentPeriod
    match employeeStatus with
    | Active -> int (januaryFirst - targettedEnrollmentDate).TotalDays
    | NotActive -> 0
```

It doesn't appear to like that `targettedEnrollmentDate` is being determined by the `DetermineTargettedEnrollmentDate` function.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only supply `DetermineTargettedEnrollmentDate` with the first argument:

```
let targettedEnrollmentDate = DetermineTargettedEnrollmentDate targettedEnrollmentPeriod
```

The result of that is a function waiting for the second argument, i.e. `targettedEnrollmentDate` is a function that takes `relativeDate` as an argument.

So, what you try to do, is subtract a function from a date and that's what the compiler complains about.

Comment: Hah, this would be a great example of being too close to the code. I had been staring at this project for so long I was starting to miss stuff like this. Thanks for the concise answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question. The code clearly doesn't compile.

`DetermineTargettedEnrollmentDate` is defined as

```
val DetermineTargettedEnrollmentDate :
  targettedEnrollmentDate:EnrollmentPeriod ->
    relativeDate:DateTime -> DateTime
```

Which means, it takes two parameters: an `EnrollmentPeriod` and a `DateTime` and returns another `DateTime`. Later in `ProjectDaysWorkedSinceJan1` you use it with just one argument:

```
let targettedEnrollmentDate = DetermineTargettedEnrollmentDate targettedEnrollmentPeriod
```

Because of [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), this makes `targettedEnrollmentDate` a function, which takes `DateTime` and return another `DateTime`. But later you try to use it as if it was a value, when you try to substract another `DateTime` from it.

```
      | Active -> int (januaryFirst - targettedEnrollmentDate).TotalDays
  ----------------------------------^

(...)

Possible overload: 'DateTime.op_Subtraction(d1: DateTime, d2: DateTime) : TimeSpan'. Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    DateTime -> DateTime    
is not compatible with type
    DateTime
```

What you probably want is to call `DetermineTargettedEnrollmentDate` with `relativeDate` instead:

```
let ProjectDaysWorkedSinceJan1 employeeStatus targettedEnrollmentPeriod (relativeDate :  DateTime) =
    let januaryFirst = DateTime(relativeDate.Year,1,1)
    let targettedEnrollmentDate = DetermineTargettedEnrollmentDate targettedEnrollmentPeriod relativeDate
    match employeeStatus with
    | Active -> int (januaryFirst - targettedEnrollmentDate).TotalDays
    | NotActive -> 0
```

Which makes it compile with following result:

```
val ProjectDaysWorkedSinceJan1 :
  employeeStatus:EmployeeStatus ->
    targettedEnrollmentPeriod:EnrollmentPeriod -> relativeDate:DateTime -> int
```